A Qute Connect Wall
Group all of these words into 4 groups. All the groups have a certain famous individual in CINEMA as their theme.











WHITE
BLONDE
HEAD
GENERAL


MAMBA
MAJOR
APACHE
SEÑOR


PINK
MOUTH
HUGO
MOUNTAIN-SNAKE


DAISY
OMAR
BROWN
BEAR




The linked individual is:

 QUENTIN TARANTINO, hinted at by the 'Q' in 'Qute' in the title (it's his initial). All the groups are connected to different films he has directed.

The groups can be resolved as follows:

 Group 1: Colours used as surnames of gang members in Reservoir Dogs (1992)
 Mr BLONDE (Michael Madsen)
 Mr BROWN (Quentin Tarantino, himself)
 Mr PINK (Steve Buscemi)
 Mr WHITE (Harvey Keitel)

Group 2: Names of members of the Basterds in Inglourious Basterds (2009)
 Aldo the APACHE (Brad Pitt)
 Donny "The BEAR Jew" Donowitz (Eli Roth)
HUGO Stiglitz (Til Schweiger)
OMAR Ulmer (Omar Doom)

Group 3: Members of the titular group in The Hateful Eight (2015)
 "Crazy" DAISY Domergue (Jennifer Jason Leigh)
GENERAL Sanford "Sandy" Smithers (Bruce Dern)
MAJOR Marquis Warren (Samuel L Jackson)
SEÑOR Bob (Demián Bichir)

Group 4: The endings of names of DeVAS members in the Kill Bill movies (2003 and 2004)
 CopperHEAD (Vivica A Fox)
 Black MAMBA (Uma Thurman)
 California MOUNTAIN-SNAKE (Daryl Hannah)
 CottonMOUTH (Lucy Liu)


Omg!! I feel like you read my mind all this time…that is just ridiculous. Good job though!

Just a minor detail, in group 2 and 3 could you name the actual groups which they all belong in.

@PDT Haha, well I do love a connecting wall :) Once I spotted the group I've labelled as #1 and clocked the significance of the title, the rest fell into place. (And yes, will modify that, no worries.)

This is what I had in mind.

@PDT I'm in the middle of an edit here - please be patient!

Sorry, I thought you had forgotten about it.

@PDT No, I had to go to a meeting! :)

You did this whilst working? That’s even more impressive. I didn’t intend this to be a coffee break puzzle.

@PDT Ha, you posted just before my lunch break, so perfect timing for me :D Couldn't quite squeeze in the extra edit you wanted before the back-to-work summons, but I hope I can usually be relied upon to finish what I've started :) Anyway, thanks for posting - back to work again now!
